# Formula to remove every middle name in a cell in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Heello,
I'm trying to remove every second and/or third name of every person in my excel file. Now i'm doing it manually (and it' s very boring). Is there any formula to to it automatically?

For example I have cell A1 that contains "Filippo Luigi Carlo", is possible to convert it to only "Filippo" ?

deleting every second and third(if the person has it) name in every cell of an excell file

Comment: You could use the function [TEXTSPLIT()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textsplit-function-b1ca414e-4c21-4ca0-b1b7-bdecace8a6e7#). Alternatively you could use a combination of the functions `LEFT()` and `SEARCH()` or `FIND()`.

Comment: Sounds like you need to replace this in-place? Select all cells you wish to replace this on, hit ctrl+f. Find ' *' (without the single quotes) and leave replace empty. Click replace all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use the following:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1),A1)
```

What does it do?

1. Finds the first space in your target text `FIND(" ", A1)`
2. Takes all the characters from the start of your target text up until the spot before the first space `LEFT(A1, {step 1} - 1)`
3. If there is an error (for example there is no space in your target text), it will simply return the original target text `=IFERROR({step 2}, A1)`

Limitations:

- The first name cannot include a space (example: `Anne Marie Jones` will return `Anne` instead of `Anne Marie`)
- Any other errors will simply return the original target text

Comment: I tried it and it works pretty well, cuz i dont get the #VALUE! error if the cell has no second name. thank you!

Comment: A neat little trick to avoid `IFERROR()` could be to use `=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1&" ")-1)`

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
=left(A1,find(" ",A1,1)-1)
```

I assumed that the first name is in cell A1, alter if not.

Based on your comment about "pier" then:

```
IF(IFERROR(FIND("pier",LEFT(A1,4),1),0)=1,A1,LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)-1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

joining the party, I assume you want to keep the first name and the last name.
The first name is given by @solar-Mike above.  For the last name, unfortunately excel only has formulae that search or find left to right, so more than two names are a problem.
[This site](https://www.exceltactics.com/reverse-string-search-excel-using-find/2/) seems to give a good solution:  a reverse find function

The formula for the last name is horrendous:
=IF(
ISERROR(
FIND(" ",A1)
),A1,RIGHT(A1,
LEN(A1)-FIND("~",
SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","~",
LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))
)
)
)
)

Tack on the bit to get the first name, and you get:

=left(A1,find(" ",A1,1)-1) & " " & IF( ISERROR( FIND(" ",A1) ),A1,RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-FIND("~", SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","~", LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")) ) ) ) )

That will drop all the middle names.

Comment: Lots of work when you only really need left(). Why check for second or third names?

Comment: it seemed a good place to park the code for something that does not have a built in function, as we move to a macro-free world