# How to do an if statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This question is linked to [Formula to remove every middle name in a cell in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75162696/formula-to-remove-every-middle-name-in-a-cell-in-excel?noredirect=1#comment132636310_75162696).

I basically want to make an if else statement in excel. So the **IF**checks if the cell **is equal** to "Gian" **OR**"Pier", if the condition is confirmed the formula proceeds to use this other formula

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2)-1),A2)
```

Sorry guys idk how to do it in an excel way. I can show you in for example in a Java or C way.

```
if(A2=="Pier" || A2=="Gian")
       =IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2)-1),A2) \\the excel formula that deletes every second/third name if the cell
```

[image]

if formula in excel that checks a condition and if its verified it proceeds to use another excel formula

Comment: `IF(OR(A2="Pier","A2="Gian"), do something if confirmed, do something else if not confirmed)`. Depending on your regional settings maybe your argument separator can be different from comma. Check [Using IF with AND, OR and NOT functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-if-with-and-or-and-not-functions-d895f58c-b36c-419e-b1f2-5c193a236d97)

Comment: If you checked my answer I gave you yesterday, you would see the use of the iF() to deal with "pier" etc That you could duplicate to deal with "Gian" etc. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75162846/4961700

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following as per your Excel Versions

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=IF(OR(TEXTBEFORE(A2&" "," ")={"Pier","Gian"}),A2,TEXTBEFORE(A2&" "," "))
```

---

Or, in cell `C2`

```
=IF(OR(LEFT(A2&" ",FIND(" ",A2&" ")-1)={"Pier","Gian"}),A2,LEFT(A2&" ",FIND(" ",A2&" ")-1))
```

---

Just adding the use of `LET()` which makes it simpler,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=LET(x,TEXTBEFORE(A2&" "," "),IF(OR(x={"Pier","Gian"}),A2,x))
```

---

Or, Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=LET(x,LEFT(A2&" ",FIND(" ",A2&" ")-1),IF(OR(x={"Pier","Gian"}),A2,x))
```

---

Using `MAP()` to Spill as one dynamic array formula but the logic remains same.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=MAP(A2:A6,LAMBDA(m,
LET(x,TEXTBEFORE(m&" "," "),
IF(OR(x={"Pier","Gian"}),m,x))))
```

---

Comment: yep yep, that's what I wanted, Rly thank you!

Comment: Sounds Good, glad you got resolved it !!! 

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the `AND(...)` and `OR(..)` for chaining logical conditions.

[Here's an example](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-if-with-and-or-and-not-functions-d895f58c-b36c-419e-b1f2-5c193a236d97)